# If the total time derivative equals zero, does the partial time derivative equal zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For all funtions $A(q(t),t)$ does $$\frac{d A(q(t),t)}{dt} =0 \implies \frac{\partial A(q(t),t)}{ \partial t} =0 $$

### Attempted answer

Essentially this question comes down to whether this PDE has non-trivial solutions

$$ \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} +  \dot{q} \frac{\partial A}{\partial q} =0 $$

Whilst I can't see why there wouldn't be I can't construct a non-trivial counter example either.

Supplementary question, whilst I think there should be a solution for specific $q(t)$, intuitively I would expect there to be no solutions of $A$ where the initial statement holds for all  $q$. Is this correct?

### Attempted answer 2

I am thinking about it now like this diagram, for a given $q$ there is no reason why the top implication would hold as they can be two different directions on my sheet $A$. If however for all $q(t)$ we have $\frac{d A(q(t),t)}{dt} =0$ then all directions must have zero variation in $A$ therefore $\frac{\partial A(q(t),t)}{ \partial t} =0$ does hold.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Re-arranging your equation yields;
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial A}{\partial q}dq = 0
\end{equation}
Now, without loss of generality, assume that we can write (i.e., without going into definitions of simply-connected open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$), we let
\begin{eqnarray}
J_{1} &=& \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} \\
J_{2} &=& \frac{\partial A}{\partial q}
\end{eqnarray}
Such that the condition
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial J_{2}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial J_{1}}{\partial q}
\end{equation}
holds, and furthermore your potential function $A$ exists if the above condition does hold. I wonder if this helps you in your quest.